# How to detect tap on wkwebview in swiftUI

Tags: swift, wkwebview

I am using wkwebview as UIViewRepresentable in SwiftUI to load html content. however, the images from the web view sometimes are too small, I would like to tap to open a new view with that Image so I am able to zoom in/out in that new new.

How can I detect a tap/click on an image from the wkwebview and also get the url of that image?